# How to do it with with loops

Tags: php

I Wanna Write a program to result as follows:

But This will be done through loop and numbers 1, 2 ,3 to 7

Result should be look like this

```
On 1 we have: 20
On 2 we have: 17
On 3 we have: 14
On 4 we have: 11
On 5 we have: 8
On 6 we have: 5
On 7 we have: 2
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why  it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time  to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also: [ask]

Comment: `for($i = 20; $i > 0; $i -= 3) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Starting off with these variables:

```
<?php
$num = 20;
$max = 7;
```

With a [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    echo 'On '.($i+1).' we have: '.($num-($i*3)).PHP_EOL;
}
```

With a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php
foreach (range(0, $max-1) as $i) {
    echo 'On '.($i+1).' we have: '.($num-($i*3)).PHP_EOL;
}
```

With a [while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i < $max) {
    echo 'On '.($i+1).' we have: '.($num-($i*3)).PHP_EOL;
    $i++;
}
```

With a [do-while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

```
<?php
$i = 0;
do {
    echo 'On '.($i+1).' we have: '.($num-($i*3)).PHP_EOL;
    $i++;
} while ($i < $max);
```

With a [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) (for fun, don't use)

```
<?php
$i = 0;
loop: {
    echo 'On '.($i+1).' we have: '.($num-($i*3)).PHP_EOL;
    $i++;
    if ($i < $max) {
        goto loop;
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/tZeOs

Many ways to do the same thing, make sure you check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Answer (score 0):

You can read about For here : [PHP : For Manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.for.php)

```
<?php
$start = 20;
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 7; $i++)
{
    if($i == 1)
    {
        echo "On $i we have : $start <br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "On $i we have : " . intval($start-3) . "<br/>";
        $start-=3;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Kinda convoluted... but it would work.